# Swift iOS -How To Reload TableView Outside Of Firebase Observer .childAdded to Filter Out Duplicate Values?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, semaphore

I have a tabBar controller with 2 tabs: tabA which contains ClassA and tabB which contains ClassB. I send data to Firebase Database in tabA/ClassA and I observe the Database in tabB/ClassB where I retrieve it and add it to a tableView. Inside the tableView's cell I show the number of sneakers that are currently inside the database.

I know the difference between `.observeSingleEvent( .value)` vs `.observe( .childAdded)`. I need live updates because while the data is getting sent in tabA, if I switch to tabB, I want to to see the new data get added to the tableView once tabA/ClassA is finished.

In ClassB I have my observer in viewWillAppear. I put it inside a `pullDataFromFirebase()` function and every time the view appears the function runs. I also have Notification observer that listens for the data to be sent in tabA/ClassA so that it will update the tableView. The notification event runs `pullDataFromFirebase()` again

In ClassA, inside the callback of the call to Firebase I have the Notification post to run the `pullDataFromFirebase()` function in ClassB.

The issue I'm running into is if I'm in tabB while the new data is updating, when it completes, the cell that displays the data has a count and the count is thrown off. I debugged it and the the sneakerModels array that holds the data is sometimes duplicating and triplicating the newly added data.

For example if I am in Class B and there are 2 pairs of sneakers in the database, the `pullDataFromFirebase()` func will run, and the tableView cell will show "You have 2 pairs of sneakers"

What was happening was if I switched to tabA/ClassA, then added 1 pair of sneakers, while it's updating I switched to tabB/ClassB, the cell would still say "You have 2 pairs of sneakers" but then once it updated the cell would say "You have 5 pairs of sneakers" and 5 cells would appear? If I switched tabs and came back it would correctly show "You have 3 pairs of sneakers" and the correct amount of cells.

That's where the Notification came in. Once I added that if I went through the same process and started with 2 sneakers the cell would say "You have 2 pairs of sneakers", I go to tabA, add another pair, switch back to tabB and still see "You have 2 pairs of sneakers". Once the data was sent the cell would briefly show "You have 5 pairs of sneakers" and show 5 cells, then it would correctly update to "You have 3 pairs of sneakers" and the correct amount of cells (I didn't have to switch tabs).

The Notification seemed to work but there was that brief incorrect moment.

I did some research and the most I could find were some posts that said I need to use a semaphore but apparently from several ppl who left comments below they said semaphores aren't meant to be used asynchronously. **I had to update my question to exclude the semaphore reference.**

Right now I'm running tableView.reloadData() in the completion handler of pullDataFromFirebase().

How do I reload the tableView outside of the observer once it's finished to prevent the duplicate values?

Model:

```
class SneakerModel{
    var sneakerName:String?
}
```

tabB/ClassB:

```
ClassB: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

var sneakerModels[SneakerModel]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pullDataFromFirebase), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "pullFirebaseData"), object: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    pullDataFromFirebase()
}

func pullDataFromFirebase(){

    sneakerRef?.observe( .childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
            let sneakerName = dict["sneakerName"] as? String

            let sneakerModel = SneakerModel()
            sneakerModel.sneakerName = sneakerName

            self.sneakerModels.append(sneakerModel)

            //firebase runs on main queue
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sneakerModels.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SneakerCell", for: indexPath) as! SneakerCell

    let name = sneakerModels[indePath.row]
    //I do something else with the sneakerName and how pairs of each I have

    cell.sneakerCount = "You have \(sneakerModels.count) pairs of sneakers"

    return cell
}

}
}
```

tabA/ClassA:

```
ClassA : UIViewController{

@IBAction fileprivate func postTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    dict = [String:Any]()
    dict.updateValue("Adidas", forKey: "sneakerName")

    sneakerRef.?.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
                (error, ref) in

        //1. show alert everything was successful

        //2. post notification to ClassB to update tableView
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "pullFirebaseData"), object: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Basically don't use semaphores to work around asynchronous data processing. Would it be an option to post the notification and run the asynchronous code (`updateChildValues`) in the receiver of the notification? Or pass the added object in the notification and update the data source array without *re-pulling* the data.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the help. Isn't that what I'm doing? The post is sent in ClassA and the receiver is ClassB. The updateChildValues is what runs in the pullFirebaseData function which is in ClassB. Why not use semaphores for async processes?

Comment: There's a right way to do stuff asynchronously. Semaphores aren't it.

Comment: No, the asynchronous task `updateChildValues` is performed in Class A and the notification is posted on completion.

Comment: @vadian my fault, your right, I overlooked what you said. I'm new to semaphores I didn't know they weren't;t meant o be used asynchronously. How can I pass the added object to the array? I can add it using a different notification but I would still have to reload the data. That's what I'm interpreting what your saying.  I didn't understand what you meant by "Would it be an option to post the notification and run the asynchronous code (updateChildValues) in the receiver of the notification? "

Comment: @matt thanks. I never used semaphores and I didn't know they couldn't be used asynchronously.

Comment: It really looks like an overcomplicated design so maybe I am missing something. Every time you switch to tab B, it's forcing a reload of data that, being Firebase, should already be available. The app allows a user to enter data on tab A and shows it on tab B, right? An alternate design: subclass NSTabViewController and keep your observers and dataSource array there. When data is entered on tab A, push it to Firebase and your tabViewController subclass will update the dataSource. When switching to tab B, simply tableView.reloadData from the array stored in the subclassed tabViewController.

Comment: The question of how to update your interface or pass information around in response to asynchronous code is _the single most frequently asked and answered question about iOS_ on Stack Overflow. I strongly suggest you search before asking. Seek and ye shall find.

Comment: @matt I've done a lot of searching I just haven't found anything specific to my question. I'm going to reword my question and exclude semaphores. I'll do more research too.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the help. I actually have way more going on then what I wrote I just narrowed it down to 2 tabs and what you see. There are 4 tabs but the problem is only happening in these 2. You said subclass  NSTabViewController . Did you mean subclass TabBarController? I also updated my question as apparently semaphores were the wrong design to use.

Comment: My apologies. I've coding macOS app and have NSTabViewController on the brain. Yes, TabBarController or really whatever the main controller is that's controlling the flow of the app. If it's really entering data on tab A and displaying it on tab B, it's just a simple matter to store keep the observers and dataSource on tab A, since B would pull the same data. The idea is to keep it in one place.

Comment: @Jay interesting, that's what vadian alluded to in an earlier comment. I'll try it and see what happens. If you have time a brief example would help though. Either way much appreciated advice!

Comment: @matt I honestly couldn't find anything on SO particular to my situation so I came up with another alternative that works quite well. I'm glad I didn't get the answer from anyone and figured it out on my own :). Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @vadian  I came up with a different resolution. I tried to use your suggestion of adding the passed object to the array without pulling it again but ran into some problems. I instead filtered out the duplicates from the array before before tableView.reload() runs and it works well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other parts of my app I use a `filterDuplicates` method that I added as an `extension` to an `Array` to filter out duplicate elements. I got it from [filter array duplicates](https://gist.github.com/SAllen0400/98f648b1b7b0014eb36552ab25f8795f):

```
extension Array {

    func filterDuplicates(_ includeElement: @escaping (_ lhs:Element, _ rhs:Element) -> Bool) -> [Element]{
        var results = [Element]()

        forEach { (element) in

            let existingElements = results.filter {
                return includeElement(element, $0)
            }

            if existingElements.count == 0 {
                results.append(element)
            }
        }

        return results
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything particular on SO to my situation so I used the filterDuplicates method which was very convenient.

In my original code I have a date property that I should've added to the question. Any way I'm adding it here and that date property is what I need to use inside the filterDuplicates method to solve my problem:

Model:

```
class SneakerModel{
    var sneakerName:String?
    var dateInSecs: NSNumber?
}
```

Inside tabA/ClassA there is no need to use the Notification inside the Firebase callback however add the dateInSecs to the dict.

tabA/ClassA:

```
ClassA : UIViewController{

@IBAction fileprivate func postTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //you must add this or whichever date formatter your using
    let dateInSecs:NSNumber? = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber?

    dict = [String:Any]()
    dict.updateValue("Adidas", forKey: "sneakerName")
    dict.updateValue(dateInSecs!, forKey: "dateInSecs")//you must add this

    sneakerRef.?.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
                (error, ref) in
             // 1. show alert everything was successful

             // 2. no need to use the Notification so I removed it
    }
}
}
```

And in tabB/ClassB inside the completion handler of the Firebase observer in the `pullDataFromFirebase()` function I used the filterDuplicates method to filter out the duplicate elements that were showing up.

tabB/ClassB:

```
func pullDataFromFirebase(){

    sneakerRef?.observe( .childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
            let sneakerName = dict["sneakerName"] as? String

            let sneakerModel = SneakerModel()
            sneakerModel.sneakerName = sneakerName

            self.sneakerModels.append(sneakerModel)

            // use the filterDuplicates method here
            self.sneakerModels = self.sneakerModels.filterDuplicates{$0.dateInSecs == $1.dateInSecs}

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Basically the filterDuplicates method loops through the sneakerModels array comparing each element to the dateInSecs and when it finds them it excludes the copies. I then reinitialize the sneakerModels with the results and everything is well.

Also take note that there isn't any need for the Notification observer inside ClassB's viewDidLoad so I removed it.